# Regex to find files without newline at the end in IntellliJ

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, newline

I'm trying to find all files without line feed character at the end of file using Find in Files menu in IntelliJ IDEA.

I've tried regex `[^\n]\Z`, but it also finds files with newlines.

What is proper regexp to do that? Or maybe there's other way to accomplish this?

Comment: On which OS are you ?

Comment: Currently on Windows

Comment: Blind guess but maybe: `[^\r][^\n]\Z` ?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Matches two last non-whitespace characters in every file. Looks like `\Z` in IDEA is an anchor last non-whitespace character in file, that's why I've asked the question.

Comment: Please post the sample strings.

Comment: Here it works and I am on Windows. Are you trying to find files without a newline (say an enter) after the last `}`?

Comment: @dambros: Here, `[^\n]\Z` [does not work](https://regex101.com/r/aM2qM5/1).

Comment: @dambros just all files without newline at the end, doesn't matter what the last character is

Comment: Try `[^\n]$(?!\n)` if `\z` does not work for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this one works! Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try small z: `[^\n]\z`

More on this [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Comment: @MichalKordas: You know, `[^\n]\z` is correct, as `\z` only matches at the end of the string. Maybe your regex flavor does not support `\z`? Then try `$(?!\n)`. Or `\Z(?!\n)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I cannot use `\Z(?!\n)` or `$(?!\n)` as I'm getting error that they match empty strings. My regex flavor is one thing, but question is specifically about IntelliJ that might do a bit more magic.

Comment: I see, please check my other suggestion posted as a comment to the question.

Comment: @MichalKordas this solution is working for me. `[^\n]\z` finds only files without a new line at the end. What version of intellij do you have? Does it list `\z` as "the end of input" when you click the 'help' link beside the regex checkbox?

Comment: @JordanShurmer I'm using the latest EAP 145.844.1. `\z` is listed, but it matches at last non-whitespace.

Comment: Very strange. I have the latest stable version and the regex is working as expected. It's possible it's a bug... since you have the Early Access version

Comment: @JordanShurmer sorry, actually it is working for me. I've just forgot to put backslash before `n`. So `[^\n]\z` is indeed the simplest solution here.

Comment: @MichalKordas: Simplest, but not that portable.

Answer (score 2):

The `$` anchor conforms to the `$` Perl-like behavior matching at the end of the sting or before the last `\n` in the string. You can still use the `$`, but restrict the end of the string with a negative lookahead.

```
[^\n]$(?!\n)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM2qM5/3)

Since `$` may match at the end of the string, but also before the last LF, the `(?!\n)` lookahead makes sure to fail the match if an LF is the last character in the string.